# Did Prof. Rabbi Umberto Cassuto have any insight behind the biblical character Yehudah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, names, shevatim-12-tribes

I am the great grandson of [Umberto Cassuto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umberto_Cassuto), Benyamin Enzo Rocca, and 5 days ago my wife and I were blessed with a son (3rd child). With his upcoming bris in a few days I would like to know if anyone has any experience or knowledge of Cassuto's writings.  Did he have any special interpretations with the stories of Yehudah?

Comment: Mazal Tov, and welcome!

Comment: There's an extended quote from his 1929 article "The Story of Tamar and Judah" [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/parsha.63/11vayigash.htm) (section G).

Comment: Ben, I [edit]ed out the part of this post with your personal contact information. You're welcome to put that in [your profile](http://yodeya.com/u/8600). (While you're at it, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.) I hope that your question here gets some interesting answers that that anyone who reads this page can enjoy.

Comment: @Fred page not found

Comment: @rikitikitembo Here's an archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150315061026/http://www.vbm-torah.org/parsha.63/11vayigash.htm

Answer (score 7):

[Nechama Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nechama_Leibowitz) used [Rabbi Cassuto](http://www.lookstein.org/nechama_parasha17_vayeshev.htm) as a source for his view of the story of Yehudah and Tamar as a punishment for the sale of Yoseph.

> 3) Measure for Measure
>
> Cassuto also believes that Yehudah’s problems in chapter 38 are
>   related to his behavior in the episode of the sale of Yosef. A
>   comparative analysis of the two narratives reveals a number of
>   linguitic and content parallels that lead Cassuto to the conclusion
>   that in chapter 38, Yehuda is being punished measure for measure (מדה
>   כנגד מדה) for his flawed behavior in chapter 37:
>
> מה שהביאני לידי דעה שאין להפריד בין הפרשה שלנו (פרשת יהודה ותמר)ובין
>   מה שקדם לה הריהי ביחוד העובדה כי בין מעשה תמר ויהודה וביןמכירת יוסף יש
>   להכיר מעין קשר פנימי המשתקף בהקבלת הניבים המורים על אותם הפרטים.[1]
>
> What has brought me to the view that our chapter (the story of Yehudah
>   and Tamar) cannot be separated from what preceded it is the fact that
>   there is a kind of internal connection between the episode of Tamar
>   and Yehudah and the episode of the sale of Yosef. This is reflected in
>   the parallelism between a number of details in one episode to details
>   in the other…
>
> Cassuto’s use of the concept “measure for measure” is reflected in the
>   following Midrash (Bereshit Rabbah 85:9), which he cites:
>
> וישלח יהודה את גדי העזים ביד רעהו" (בראשית לח:כ): …התורה היא משחקת על
>   הבריות. אמר הקב"ה ליהודה: "אתה רמית לאביך בגדי עזים, חייך שתמר מרמה בך
>   בגדי עזים.
>
> And Yehuda sent the young goat in the hand of his friend” (Bereshit
>   38:20): … The Torah mocks mankind. God said to Yehudah: “You deceived
>   your father with a young goat, by your life Tamar will deceive you
>   with a young goat.”
>
> Because Yehudah and his brothers stained Yosef’s coat with the blood
>   of a young goat in order to trick their father into believing that
>   Yosef had been killed, Yehudah was tricked by Tamar with a young goat.
>   This is but one of the parallels between the two narratives that
>   support Cassuto’s interpretation. The following are a number of
>   additional corresponding elements in the two stories:
>
> ויהי כאשר בא יוסף אל אחיו ויפשיטו את יוסף את כותנתו…
>
> (בראשית לז:כג)
>
> ויגד לתמר לאמר הנה חמיך עלה תמנתה לגז צאנו. ותסר בגדי אלמנותה… (בראשית
>   לח:יג-יד)
>
> And it was told to Tamar saying: “Behold your father-in-law is going
>   up to Timna to shear his sheep.” And she removed her widow’s garments
>   …
>
> (Bereshit 38:14)
>
> And it was when Yosef came to his brothers, and they removed Yosef’s
>   coat from him…
>
> (Bereshit 37:23)
>
> וישלחו את כתונת הפסים ויביאו אל אביהם ויאמרו זאת מצאנו הכר נא הכתונת
>   בנך הוא אם לא.
>
> (בראשית לז:לב)
>
> הוא מוצאת והיא שלחה אל חמיה לאמר לאיש אשר אלה לו אני הרה ותאמר הכר נא
>   למי החותמת והפתילים והמטה האלה.(בראשית לח:כה)
>
> When she was brought forth, she sent to her father-in-law saying: “By
>   the man to whom these belong I am pregnant.” And she said: “Identify
>   please whose are these signet, cord and staff.
>
> (Bereshit 38:25)
>
> And they sent the coat of many colors and brought it to their father,
>   and said: “This we have found. Identify please if it is the coat of
>   your son or not.”
>
> (Bereshit 37:32)
>
> This comparison indicates that the deceptions in the sale of Yosef and
>   the story of Yehuda and Tamar were parallel from beginning to end. It
>   is interesting to note that the following Midrash, found in the
>   Schechter Genizah, also utilizes the parallel appearance of the young
>   goat to explain the sale of Yosef as a “measure for measure”
>   punishment for Ya’akov:
>
> "וישחטו שעיר עזים"(בראשית לז:לא): משלם הקב"ה לבני אדם מדה כנגד
>   מדה,ואפילו לצדיקי עולם משלם מדה כנגד מדה. יעקב אבינו רימה באביו
>   בעורותגדיי עזים ובניו רימו בו בגדי עזים... (תורה שלמה, וישב לז:קפא)
>
> And they slaughtered a young goat (Bereshit 37:31) - God repays man
>   measure for measure, and even pays the righteous of the world measure
>   for measure. Our father Ya’akov deceived his father using the skins of
>   a young goat, and his sons deceived him with a young goat …(Torah
>   Shleimah, Vayeshev 37:181)
>
> Conclusion
>
> A combined look at the commentaries on the stories of Yosef and
>   Yehudah reveal an important common thread between the two events –
>   that both stories must be viewed from both the human and Divine
>   perspectives. Each story involves a drama in which human frailty leads
>   to tragedy, and confrontation with that frailty leads to regeneration.
>   In both stories, as well, the human drama unfolds within a larger
>   picture that is driven by a Divine plan. As such, we can understand
>   that ultimately from these two episodes emerged the two redeemers of
>   Israel – Mashiach ben Yosef, and Mashiach ben David.[2]
>
> [1] קסוטו, ב. ד., "מעשה תמר ויהודה" בציונים, הוצאת אשכול, ברלין תרפ"ט,
>   דפים 93-100.
>
> [2] There is a tradition among Jewish thinkers that there will be two
>   stages to the messianic redemption involving the advent of two
>   messianic figures – Mashiach ben Yosef and Mashiach ben David.
>   Mashiach ben Yosef is described as a warrior who will effect the
>   national reunification of the Jewish people prior to the arrival of
>   Mashiach ben David.